# Using PHPExcel in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla1.5, phpexcel

I've been trying to get PHPExcel to work with my Joomla. If the script saves it into file, it works fine but when I'm trying to output it to the browser for download, the file will give a warning 'File extension or file format is not valid'. My guess would be something to do with the Content-Type being served. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Headers I've placed in view.xlsx.php:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

This is actually a copy and paste from their example which I can assure works fine in their own script. The problem is when I'm running it in Joomla.

Comment: Please look into the actual file contents that get output using a text editor. Chances are there are error messages in there

Comment: Tried it and no, there's only gibberish data in there.

Comment: It isn't actually gibberish, it's a zipped collection of xml files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this entr](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=433060)y from the Joomla forums; and watch out for potential clashes with the [autoloader](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=211925)

Comment: Ahh just what I needed. Been searching far and wide for that. Thanks!